# Autodesk Data Visualization Extension chronos-etu module error: t is read-only

Tags: autodesk-forge, readonly, autodesk-viewer

I am trying to integrate the time slider from chronos-etu in my React app, as part of the Data Visualization Extension, but I keep getting this error when clicking the `play` button:

`Error: "t" is read-only`

[image: Chronos-etu time slider]

I think it's coming from this function in the `chronos-etu.js` module:

```
play(e) {
    let t;
    void 0 !== e && (t = new s.MomentInstant(e)),
    this._chronosManger.setPlaybackPlayState(0, t)
}
```

I checked and `pause` and `stop` don't have this problem.

Does anyone know why this happens and how it can be solved?

Comment: Could you try to upgrade `chronos-etu`  to v5.1.1 to see if it helps?

Comment: I did, but it doesn't change much, since the ```forge-dataviz-iot-react-components``` package requires ```chronos-etu v3.1.0``` in its dependencies.

Comment: Not sure how you made the change, but I can override it like this line: https://github.com/yiskang/forge-dataviz-iot-react-components-es5/blob/main/package.json#L18 and the play function is working. See https://www.yiskang.tw/forge-dataviz-iot-react-components-es5/

Comment: To make the change take effect, you need to remove the whole `node_modules` folder first, then run npm `install` again.

Comment: It only worked after I manually upgraded ```chronos-etu``` package in the ```forge-dataviz-iot-react-components```, not only upgrading it in my project. This could be solved if in the dependency list of ```forge-dataviz-iot-react-components``` package, ```chronos-etu``` has ```v5.1.1``` instead of ```v3.1.0```. Is it possible to make this change? Otherwise every time we pull the forge package again, it changes the ```chronos-etu``` to its original version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solution**:
The `chronos-etu` package needs to be upgraded from `v3.1.0` to `v5.1.1` both in the main project and in the `forge-dataviz-iot-react-components` folder in the `ClientApp\node_modules` folder. See the comments above for more details.

**Note**:
I think that this could be solved if in the dependency list of `forge-dataviz-iot-react-components` package, `chronos-etu` is changed from `v3.1.0` to `v5.1.1`. Otherwise every time we pull the `forge-dataviz-iot-react-components` package, it will change the `chronos-etu` to its original version.